# Can I use UIBezierPath to draw a shadow image around a UITableView section?

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a shadow image that I would like to draw around the outer edge of a grouped UITableView section. This is the image:

[image]

I can get the UIBezierPath that represents the rect I want to draw around, but I can't figure out how to repeat the image along the route of the rect. So far it just fills the rect with the image:

```
UIImage *patternImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellShadow"];
UIColor *fill = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImg];
[fill setFill];
CGRect aSectRect = [self rectForSection:0];
UIBezierPath *aSectPath = [self createRoundedPath:aSectRect];
[aSectPath fill];
```

Is this possible? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to have UIBezierPath use an image as a "brush" which is essentially what you'd want. But you can have CoreGraphics draw a shadow for you:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeZero, myShadowRadius);
// Draw your shape here
```

Now if you draw just one shape it will get a shadow. But if you draw more shapes, each will get its own shadow which might not be what you want. The solution is called a transparency layer, which is not related to CALayers or something but is just some kind of "grouping" in CoreGraphics:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeZero, myShadowRadius);
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
// Draw your shapes here.
CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
```

Between the `CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer` and `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` calls the shadow is disabled. After the `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` call, the shadow is applied to everything that has been drawn between *begin* and *end* as if it were just one shape.